# ¿Como convertir una imagen a un array de bytes en java?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Estoy tratando de convertir una imagen a un arreglo de bytes en java para poder guardarlo en una base de datos, eh usado varios métodos para realizar la conversión, y podría decirse que si lo hace, pero siempre me devuelve una pequeña parte, este uno de los códigos que he ocupado:

```
public byte[] extractBytes(File imgPath) throws IOException {

        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imgPath);

        RecortaFotografia recorte = new RecortaFotografia(bufferedImage, 100, 100);

        WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
        DataBufferByte data = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();

        return (data.getData());
    }
```

Pero el resultado siempre es algo similar a esto:

```
[B@172675af
```

He utilizado otros métodos para la conversión y el resultado siempre es el mismo. No encuentro mi error, o que estoy haciendo mal. ¿Por que siempre me devuelve solo una parte? o ¿como puedo obtener toda la cadena del array de bytes?

Comment: Estas obteniendo el valor del objeto que retorna  tu método. Quizá estas haciendo `System.out.println( extractBytes(new File ("")) ;`

Answer (score 2):

> Pero el resultado siempre es algo similar a esto:
>
> ```
> [B@172675af
> ```

Es completamente normal por qué estás imprimiendo un **objeto**. Cuando imprimes un objeto -si no has sobreescrito el método `toString` lo que obtendrás es:

```
NombreClase@hashcode
```

Son nociones básicas. Para imprimir tu arreglo de byte deberías hacer un simple for:

```
for(byte b : bytes) { System.out.print(b); }
```

O al estilo lambda:

```
Arrays.stream(bytes).forEach(System.out::print);
```

---

Una forma fácil de convertir una imagen a `byte[]` es esta:

```
public static Optional<byte[]> toBinary(String path) {
    int len = path.split("\\.").length;
    String ext = path.split("\\.")[len - 1];
    try {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(img, ext, baos);
        return Optional.of(baos.toByteArray());
    } catch(IOException e) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Y la usaríamos así:

```
Optional<byte[]> binary = ImageUtils.toBinary("ruta-abs-imagen");
// la imagen se procesó sin problemas y hay datos
if(binary.isPresent()) {
    byte[] image = binary.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El resultado es el valor del `Objeto` que retorna tu método, quizá obtienes el valor de la siguiente forma

```
/* Por eso Obtienes ese valor */
System.out.println(extractBytes(new File("urlImage")));
```

- La primera parte de esta salida muestra el [Tipo de Objeto](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Classes,_Objects_and_Types) en su caso `B` que es `Byte`
- La segunda parte es la representación `hexadecimal` de la [hashCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) de su objeto.`(172675af)`

Para Obtener los valores que retorna su `método` debería recibirlos antes.. una forma sencilla de hacer dicha operación sería.

```
   byte[] retorno = extractBytes(new File("urlfile"));
    /* Imprimir los Bytes */
    for (byte s : retorno) {
        System.out.println(s& 0xff); 
     /* Si quiere hacer sus valores Positivos sino simplemente sout(s) */
    }
```

> Otra forma para imprimir (Si desea hacerlo) sería usando la clase
>   `Arrays`y  su método [toString(byte[] array)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(byte[]))